# Where can I find stories from people moving from a Windows OS?

Tags: software-recommendation, distro-recommendation

I am seeking a place where to find stories of individuals and businesses that may have switched from a Windows OS to Ubuntu and were/are happy with their switch and why?

Comment: I think you should start searching globally and particularly on the blogs of people who switched from their original OS (not only Windows). Unfortunately your question seems not to have an answer to a specific problem, thus it will be closed soon.

Comment: As it is a "Where can I find" question I think it is reasonable to ask and to answer it with a URL or publication. (askubuntu itself isn't the place to compile the stories sought, however.).

Answer (score 2):

I switched from using windows XP almost exclusively, to using Ubuntu exclusively about a year ago.  I made the switch because my installation of XP broke.  A re-install was not possible because I lost the product key.

The switch to Ubuntu was pretty brutal.  I needed my computer for college work etc. and it really took me a while to get used to.  Naturally I was looking for a windows like UI so I decided to try Kubuntu after a while.  This I did not like for some reason.  (KDE is a bit cumbersome I think).

I decided to try openSUSE because of their commitment to KDE, but I couldn't get used to YaST.  I tried some others (Debian and Arch Linux), but due to my rather limitted knowledge of the Linux OS I didn't get very far.  Eventually, I ended up using good ol' ubuntu again.  Since I hadn't used Ubuntu in the GNOME 2 era, Unity did not bother me so much.

When 12.10 came out I upgraded (which broke my install).  Rather than re-install ubuntu I figured I should try some other linux flavours.  Eventually I stuck with Arch Linux.  I stuck with it because I loved the minimalistic system I was able to build, as well as the pacman package manager.

On my laptop I still use Ubuntu because it requires much less maintainance than arch, and handles WI-FI connectivity out of the box.

At work I also use Ubuntu (I had no choice really), but I use the xfce desktop environment because it runs smoother on the hardware.

I have also recently re-installed windows (windows seven this time) for compatibility reasons, and because I like gaming.

My conclusion is that, unless you are intending to game or require specific software, Linux (which distro does not matter so much) is a superior OS, especially for software development.

As for Ubuntu itself, it is certainly not my favourite distro, (I prefer more lightweight alternatives) but with the xfce or lxde desktop environment it is very usable.  By far my favourite though is Arch Linux.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux

Comment: It is off-topic on this site to ask questions or to provide answers regarding operating systems other than Ubuntu or official derivatives of Ubuntu. The site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is more fit for that. Moreover, the question will be closed soon as this is an opinion based question not very much fit for a Q&A site. See the help pages for what is on-topic here. http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @gertvdijk My bad I was not aware of this.  What should be my course of action?  Should I delete/edit my post?

Comment: After some more close votes come it the whole question will be closed and removed (together with your answer) not soon after most likely.

Comment: @gertvdijk, you did nothing wrong. Thanks for trying to help Mike.